# Wie kam es zu der Wendung "jemand hängen lassen"?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Eine sehr gebräuchliche Redewendung ist *"jemand [hängen lassen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/haengen_lassen)"* (*to let someone down*)

> Unser Lieferant hat uns wieder einmal hängen lassen.

Woher kommt dieser Ausdruck?

Comment: Na gut, na gut... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt, wie zu fast allen Redewendungen, sehr viele Ansätze und Erklärungen. Ein möglicher Stamm von "jemanden hängen lassen" liegt in den mittelalterlichen Ritterturnieren:

Wurde ein Ritter beim Turnier vom Pferd gestoßen, kam es vor, dass er mit dem Fuß im Steigbügel hängen blieb. Kam der Knappe nicht zu Hilfe, dann hat er seinen Herrn "hängen lassen". Er ließ ihn damit auch "im Stich", also dem Stich der gegnerischen Lanze ausgeliefert.

Die oben erwähnte Erklärung mit dem Korb würde ich mit Vorsicht betrachten.

Answer (score 0):

Ich meine mal gehört zu haben, das komme aus der Gaunersprache. Wenn einer der Gauner gefangen worden ist, und die anderen ihn nicht befreit haben, haben sie ihn [(er-)hängen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erh%C3%A4ngen) lassen -- zugelassen, dass er gehängt wird.

Wenn ich wieder in der Nähe meines etymologischen Wörterbuchs bin, versuche ich das mal zu  verifizieren.

Answer (score 0):

Im [Wikipedia-Artikel zur Redensart *Einen Korb geben*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einen_Korb_geben)  steht Folgendes

> [...] In einer weiteren Variation des Motives lässt das umworbene Fräulein den Korb mitsamt Freier auf halber Höhe zu ihrem Fenster hängen, worauf dieser am nächsten Morgen zum Gespött der Leute wird. Hierauf fußt womöglich die Redensart „jemanden (in der Luft) hängen lassen“.

Comment: Hahahahahahaha!

Comment: Frage mich, ob das sein kann. Das Fräulein kompromitiert sich damit und stellt sich selbst bloß. Habe den Eindruck, das ist eine zusammengereimte Erklärung.

Comment: Das muss ja ein Mordsweib sein Kerl im Korb zum Fenster rein wuchtet. :-)